# Devise redirect and display error messages on fail with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have been reviewing all of the solutions to getting the redirect to work. I went with overriding the registrations controller and the redirect works however where I am falling short is getting the simple form to process the errors. If I do via the standard routing to the devise view it shows up with the proper errors and css, however, when I do it on the redirect to my root_path(pages#index) route I don't see anything and the form is unchanged.

Form code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-group top">
      <%= f.input :name, required: true, placeholder: "George Washington" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :email, required: true, placeholder: "Your.email.address@email.com" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: "7 characters minimum. No emojis allowed." %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Sign me up and get me my key", class: "btn btn-wide thirdy" %>
      <small class="note">By submitting your information you are agreeing to our Terms & Conditions.</small>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: "registrations"
  }

  get 'pages/index'
  get 'docs', to: 'pages#docs', as: 'docs'

  root to: 'pages#index'
end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def docs
  end
end
```

Comment: was you able to fix it?

Comment: I did and thank you again for your follow up. The problem I had was the resource scope not being configured correctly. I added the configuration to the application_helper.rb and then override the registrations controller 'create' method. On error I then 'render' not 'redirect_to' which was destroying the user object with the error messages I needed. I am going to edit my post to better illustrate my solution. Thank you again for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

When you redirect, you actually clean the post body - so you don't have any of that information available to process. So you will not see any error - what makes sense.

What I usually do is to render the partial/view again. Take the following example:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  else
    # You have `params` with all the form data here
    # and also `@user.errors` with data from the validations
    render :new
  end
end
```

With the `render :new`, I'll render the form again, showing the errors.

I believe you need to do something similar over there in order to show the errors.

But, I don't recommend overwriting the create action like that - I would update the `RegistrationsController` to something like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  private

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end
end
```

Devise uses the template pattern to allow you to change the destination after the sign up process.

If you want to show a different `view` in case it fails - like your `page/index`, you will have to create a `create.html.erb` template file with that content inside the `registrations` template folder.

## A workaround for your problem

To make it render your `page/index` in case registration fails, I would extract that code to a partial, and also to a helper in `ApplicationController` all the things you need to do in order to render that page.

So, in case you have an `index` action like this (with some content being loaded there):

```
def index
  @recent_news = News.recent_news
  @recent_users = User.recent_users
  @tags = Tag.ordered_by_number
end
```

I would extract its content to something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def load_recent_content_and_tags # probably a better naming here
    @recent_news = News.recent_news
    @recent_users = User.recent_users
    @tags = Tag.ordered_by_number
  end
end
```

The new `PagesController#index` would be like:

```
def index
  load_recent_content_and_tags
end
```

And then, in your `RegistrationsController`:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super do |resource|
      if resource.errors.present?
        load_recent_content_and_tags
        render 'pages/index' and return
      end
    end
  end 

  private

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end
end
```

I haven't tested it, but I believe it might work as you want.

Comment: Davis, thank you! I will give it try and let you know. I didn't like my implementation regarding the controller either.

Comment: No, that was just an example to illustrate how a regular flow works - when you submit a form, the data is available in that action, if you redirect, it will not be there anymore. What do you want exactly? Could you explain/elaborate more about the user journey?

Comment: Yes. I have a form for sign_up that's embedded in the index/home page. When I submit and get errors I want to return to index with the sign up form and display the errors. When I submit and force errors it redirects to the devise view. I did create the template view to match the controller but it still redirects to the devise defaults. Let me know if more elaboration is required.

Comment: I'll update my answer with something that you might try.

Comment: I've added a new section, `A workaround for your problem`, that I hope help you.